# Bluetooth Indicator Applet menu disappears before I can click on it if Panel is set to auto-hide

Tags: lubuntu, bluetooth, lxpanel

I've just installed Lubuntu 15.10 on an old netbook that was dying under the weight of Windows 7, and so far I'm loving it. Much of what I learned when I had to do admin on Unix systems back in the early 90s is coming back to me (and much as changed).

Anyway, on to the point of my post. Because of the small netbook screen (1024x600), I have my LXPanel at the bottom of the screen set to auto-hide. The problem occurs if I try to use the menu that pops up from the Bluetooth Indicator Applet. Very shortly after I move my mouse off the panel and onto the menu (while still holding down the left button), the panel auto-hides itself, and the menu vanishes. This makes it impossible to use unless I'm really fast navigating to the item I want (which I'm mostly not).

I think this is a bug in the panel. It should not hide if a menu from something on the panel is open. Or maybe it's a bug in the BIA not informing the panel that the menu is open?

Is there a way to at least lengthen the auto-hide delay for the panel, as a work-around for this issue? I was unable to find one.

Comment: Report that this bug affects you in:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lxde-common/+bug/1547892
Or here:
https://sourceforge.net/p/lxde/bugs/800/

Answer (score 1):

For me the simplest work around is to click the applet and use the keyboard to navigate the menu.  I like the binding solution, too.

Comment: Actually a really good answer!

Answer (score 0):

This answer *doesn't fix the autohide timeout issue* you ask about but is a `workaround`.

I suggest you *switch off the autohide feature*. Instead, you use a "toggle" to make `lxpanel` appear or disappear as you wish.

Use a text editor to create a file called `lxpanel-toggle` with the following contents:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if pgrep lxpanel
then 
  pkill lxpanel
else 
  lxpanel --profile whatever
fi
```

Obviously, instead of `whatever` you'll use the name given in `~/.config/lxpanel`, probably `Lubuntu`.

You'll save this file in the folder that holds all your user-level scripts. I keep my scripts in `~/bin` which should be in your `PATH` by default. (You can check that by running `env | grep -E "^PATH"`.)

Then, make `lxpanel-toggle` executable by right-clicking on it in PCManFM > Properties > Permissions.

After this, edit `~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml`, making sure you've backed up the file in case of any mishap.

Look for a unique line that has just `</keyboard>`. Then, very carefully, paste in the following code just above that line:

```
    <keybind key="C-S-L">        # Toggle lxpanel
      <action name="Execute"><command>/home/your_username/bin/lxpanel-toggle</command></action>
    </keybind>
```

where you'll replace `your_username` with *your* login username.

Save the modified version of `~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml`.

Open a terminal and run

```
openbox --reconfigure
```

each time you modify and save `lubuntu-rc.xml` to make Openbox aware of the changes.

After this, you can toggle `lxpanel` to appear and disappear at your pleasure by pressing <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>. The exact choice of keys is up to you and you need to ensure that the combination isn't already used for some other function. Read http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Bindings#Key_combination for more detail.